# How to return to the line when you reach the end of the card?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a card, and inside it, I have a variable which can be very long. I'm doing this `{!!substr($myVariable->text, 0, 275)!!}`, which show the 275 first caracter of the variable. But the problem is this :

[image]

How can I display all the text without this slide bar please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS.

```
.example{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

I *think* you also need to use the Facade in front of the `substr` method like:
`Str::substr()`

Answer (score 2):

I think the best is you add a `<p>` tag to the body of your card and specify the `width="100%" for the`

` tag.

and I agree with

```
Str::substr($myVariable->text, 0, 275)
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-substr

```
Str::substr()
The Str::substr method returns the portion of the string specified by the start and length parameters:

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$converted = Str::substr('The Laravel Framework', 4, 7);

// Laravel
```

thanks to [@Bennett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3903390/bennett)